# Any way to override wifi requirement for downloading apps/app updates larger than 150MB?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

Right now (on iOS 12 beta version 1) if you try to download an app or app update larger than 150MB it requires a wifi connection. Problem is, I just moved into a new place with wifi not as speedy as my old place and my LTE provides much quicker downloads.

Any way to override this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best wayto do that is to tether to another mobile device so that your iPhone on the beta sees a WiFi connection. I know this is a workaround and not a solution, but I’ve not heard of any way to trick / hack / override this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just so I'm clear: I have my old 5s sitting right here. You're saying, connect that to wifi and tether my current iPhone to it? Or must the other mobile device also have access to data?

Comment: @A.fm. Without jailbreak you need cellular data to tether AFAIK. I don’t know why you don’t just connect both phones to WiFi if you have that for the 5s you should have that for the other phone.

Comment: Well the 5s does connect for the very limited use I still have for it (aka testing some beta apps, playing around with iOS 10.3.3, etc). The 7+ can connect to WiFi, too, of course, but I mentioned above that it's so. dang. slow. That I end up finding it far quicker to download apps or updates over LTE.

Comment: Not as slow as passing all the traffic through the 5s (lol I think)